# ServiceProvider registered but not work in controller

Tags: php, laravel, service-provider

I registered a `ServiceProvider` with [**easysms**](https://github.com/overtrue/easy-sms)

*app\Providers\EasySmsServiceProvider.php*

```php
<?php
namespace App\Providers;

use Overtrue\EasySms\EasySms;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class EasySmsServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider{

    public function register(){

        $this->app->singleton(EasySms::class, function($app){
            return new EasySms(config('easysms'));
        });

        $this->app->alias(EasySms::class, 'easysms');
    }
}
```

then, I add it to `config/app.php` in `providers`

*config/app.php*

```php
    'providers' => [
        ...
        // easysms
        App\Providers\EasySmsServiceProvider::class,
    ],
```

I already checked `bootstrap/cache/services.php` and I am sure I registered it successful.

[image: bootstrap/cache/services.php details]

But when I try to use it in `Controller`, errors occurred, it seems like something wrong with `EasySmsServiceProvider`
[image: errors in postman]

here is my controller

*app\Http\Controllers\V1\Auth\VerifySmsesController.php*

```php
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers\V1\Auth;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests\V1\Auth\VerifySmsRequest;
use Overtrue\EasySms\EasySms;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use Cache;

class VerifySmsesController extends Controller{

    public function store(VerifySmsRequest $request, EasySms $easySms){

        $phone = $request->phone;
        $code = str_pad(random_int(1, 999999), 6, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT);

        try {
            $result = $easySms->send($phone, [
                'template' => config('easysms.gateways.aliyun.templates.register'),
                'data' => [
                    'code' => $code
                ],
            ]);
        } catch (\Overtrue\EasySms\Exceptions\NoGatewayAvailableException $exception) {
            $message = $exception->getException('aliyun')->getMessage();
            abort(500, $message ?: 'Errors In Sending SMS');
        }

        $key = 'verify_code_' . Str::random(15);
        $expiredAt = now()->addMinutes(5);
        Cache::put($key, ['phone' => $phone, 'code' => $code], $expiredAt);
        return response()->json([
            'key' => $key,
            'expired_at' => strtotime($expiredAt->toDateTimeString()),
        ],201);
    }
}
```

here is my `routes/api.php`

```php
<?php 
Route::group([
    'prefix' => 'v1',
    'name' => 'v1.',
    'namespace' => 'V1'
], function(){

    Route::group([
        'prefix' => 'auth',
        'name' => 'auth.',
        'namespace' => 'Auth',
        'middleware' => ['throttle:'.config('api.rate_limits.sign')]
    ], function(){

        Route::resource('verify-smses', 'VerifySmsesController', ['only' => ['store']]);
    });
});
```

I had try commands below to clear/reset my config, but nothing helps

```
php artisan config:clear
php artisan clear-compiled
composer dump-autoload
php artisan optimize
```

also when I try to use `$result = app('easysms')->send(...)` instead of `$result = $easySms->send(...)` above

[image]

still errors

I am using Laravel 7.8.1.

How can I fix these errors? Thanks a lot~

---***update***---

*config/easysms.php*

```php
<?php 
use \Overtrue\EasySms\Strategies\OrderStrategy;
return [
    'timeout' => 10.0,
    'default' => [
        'strategy' => OrderStrategy::class,
        'gateways' => [
            'aliyun',
        ],
    ],
    'gateways' => [
        'errorlog' => [
            'file' => '/tmp/easy-sms.log',
        ],
        'aliyun' => [
            'access_key_id' => env('SMS_ALIYUN_SMS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
            'access_key_secret' => env('SMS_ALIYUN_SMS_ACCESS_KEY_SECRET'),
            'sign_name' => env('SMS_ALIYUN_SMS_SIGN_NAME'),
            'templates' => [
                'register' => env('SMS_ALIYUN_SMS_TEMPLATE_REGISTER')
            ]
        ],
    ],
];
```

---***update***---

it works when I run code below in `php artisan tinker` directly

```php
$sms = app('easysms');
try {
    $sms->send($phone, [
         'template' => config('easysms.gateways.aliyun.templates.register'),
         'data' => [
             'code' => 1234
         ],
    ]);
} catch (\Overtrue\EasySms\Exceptions\NoGatewayAvailableException $exception) {
    $message = $exception->getException('aliyun')->getMessage();
    dd($message);
}
```

Comment: Have  you checked if config('easysms') returns an array? And if this array is what the class expects?

Comment: @ArthurSamarcos Yes, I follow the [README of easysms](https://github.com/overtrue/easy-sms/blob/master/README.md) and I coded exactly as it guided, I had already added `config/easysms.php` in my question.

Comment: @ArthurSamarcos Thank you! I fixed it by `php artisan cache:clear` 